# Android: SwipeListView click

Tags: android, swipe

SwipeListView is working good,but sometimes have a problem that the "swipeBackView" item should be clicked if we click at the corresponding position at "swipeFrontView".Help me please and Thanks in advance.
My xml codes are as follows:

activity_home.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

    <com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/lstRequests"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
        swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
        swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeMode="left" >
    </com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView

 </RelativeLayout>
```

package_row.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/back"             <===
        style="@style/ListBackContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="110dp"   
        android:tag="back" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/backshowportion"
        style="@style/ListBackContent"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:gravity="right|center" >

        <TextView
             ..... />

        <TextView
             ..... />

        <TextView 
             ...../>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/front"            <===
        style="@style/ListFrontContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="front" >

        <TextView
             ..... />

        <TextView
             ..... />

        <TextView
             ..... />

        <TextView
             ..... />


</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and the a portion of Class Code is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
swipeListView=(SwipeListView)findViewById(R.id.lstRequests);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) 
{
    swipeListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
{
    swipeListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,long id, boolean checked)
        {
            mode.setTitle("Selected (" + swipeListView.getCountSelected() + ")");                  
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) 
        {
            swipeListView.unselectedChoiceStates();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode,MenuItem item) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
public void onStart()
{
super.onStart();        
listner(); 
}
private void listner()
{
 swipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() 
 {          
        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right)
        {
             Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartOpen %d - action %d", position, action));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right)
        {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));                 
        }   

        @Override
        public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight)
        {   

        }   

        @Override
        public void onMove(int position, float x)
        {

        }   

        @Override
        public void onListChanged()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLastListItem()
        {   

        }   

        @Override
        public void onFirstListItem()
        {   

        }   

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) 
        {

        }

        @Override           
        public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) 
        {   

        }   

        @Override
        public void onClickFrontView(int position)
        {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickFrontView %d", position));
            swipeListView.openAnimate(position);
        }   

        @Override
        public void onClickBackView(int position)
        {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));
            swipeListView.closeAnimate(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChoiceStarted() 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChoiceEnded() 
        {   

        }   

        @Override
        public void onChoiceChanged(int arg0, boolean arg1) 
        {

        }   

        @Override
        public int onChangeSwipeMode(int arg0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no need of layout file code. Please post some java file code also.

Comment: Added the code segment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified the FrontView of the package_row.xml by making that RlativeLayout clickable as follows and its working properly now,.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/front"
  style="@style/ListFrontContent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="110dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:tag="front" >
```